# Solana/web3.js - Problems with confirmTransaction

Tags: web3.js, transaction, confirmtransaction

I'm having trouble using confirmTransaction properly. I expect that the call won't return until the conditions are met (either it is confirmed or blockheight exceeded). However, I frequently get a response, but then an attempt to retrieve the transaction **fails** (returns null). Most of the time the transaction does go through, but it's already passed the point in my program where I am expecting to retrieve the transaction.

Other times, confirmTransaction returns a TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError error, but then an attempt to retrieve the transaction **succeeds**.

Ultimately, I need to understand how to properly use confirmTransaction to reliably determine when to retry a transaction.

Here's a snip

```
let latestBH = await solanaConnection.getLatestBlockhash('confirmed');
let confirmation = await solanaConnection.confirmTransaction({
    blockhash: latestBH.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: latestBH.lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature: txHash
}, 'confirmed');

// confirmation response
{
    "context": {
        "slot": 223810433
    },
    "value": {
        "err": null
    }
}

let txResult = await solanaConnection.getTransaction(txHash, {
    commitment: 'confirmed', 
    preflightCommitment: 'confirmed', 
    maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 1
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you're sometimes hitting different backends that have forked.

For example, if the confirmation is expiring even though it's later confirmed, the node you're accessing could have forked off. On the other hand, if you're failing to retrieve the transaction later, it could be that the node you're accessing again forked off and never included that transaction.

As for retrying transactions, the idea is to gradually retry broadcasting until you're sure that it lands, and only re-sign if you know that it didn't go through. There's more information at https://solanacookbook.com/guides/retrying-transactions.html#retrying-transactions

Comment: I appreciate the response. So in the event that confirmTransaction returns and a subsequent getTransaction fails, does that mean the transaction *did* go through and I just need to wait to retrieve the transaction? At that point, is there still a chance that the transaction will fail?

Comment: if `confirmTransaction` works for the `confirmed` commitment, you can be practically sure that it went through. It's technically possible for the transaction to be reverted, but it has never happened in practice.

Answer (score 0):

what i usually fo is that i write a recursive function that calls itself every 5/10 secs to check if the transaction exists with the given signature, and then use the parsed transaction to check if there was an error.
And you can stop this script after X attempts (but it doesn't really mean that the transaction didn't went thru, it could be that you haven't waited long enough).

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I was hoping to use confirmTransaction to perform this sort of logic more precisely. It could be that I need to use these concepts together – confirmTransaction followed by a polling of getTransaction.